# Progressbar.js - how to get a second circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar

I'm currently trying to get a second progressbar in my document with progressbar.js

I've managed to get one that even draws the progressbar percentage from the value attribute of the circle in the html document. So far I can't get the second one working. Could anybody help me out here?

http://codepen.io/stephan-v/pen/MwQQzJ

```
var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
var endColor = '#9ec64d';

window.onload = function onLoad() {
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('.progress', {
        color: startColor,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'bounce',
        strokeWidth: 8,

        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        }
    });

    // This will get the number from the page
    var value = ($('.progress').attr('value') / 100);

    // This will determine the circumference of the circle
    circle.animate(value, {
        from: {color: startColor},
        to: {color: endColor}
    });
};
```

I've got the javascripts from: http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

I just need to display multiple progressbars in a single page. I would be so happy if somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same class names make a conflict here

I added `progress2` class value to second one

```
<div class="progress" value="75"></div>
<div class="progress2" value="25"></div>
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOqqeG)

Comment: I see. I'm not that experienced with javascript and I might have about 10 progressbars on my page at one time. Would you maybe know a better solution to this? Just giving me a hint in the right direction would help a lot already.

Comment: ok i ve change it to easy to integrate, check new codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOqqeG